# background image should be in diagonal using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on my portfolio. I have the Image in the body I want the image should be in diagonal using only css / css3 / Jquery Not by editing through photoshop I have tried using transform rotate for the body.

But I am not getting the result.

Here I have fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qznnyxo3/1/)

Here is the css code for that

```
.fullimg{
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/swudrIP.png') no-repeat fixed center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I want my output should look like below css class name

```
.diagonal{
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/ugmhC7w.png?1') no-repeat fixed center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a psuedo-element for this if you wish to apply it to the body, as opposed to using a child element such as a div.

```
.fullimg:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/swudrIP.png);
}
```

[Link to the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xn3bgrx/)

Comment: hi @Ohgodwhy I am not getting the result can you please explain me a bit

Comment: @MahadevanSivasubramanian What's not working about it? The `:before` creates a [psuedo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before). The `:before` element specifically creates a psuedo first-child element to the parent it's attached to. If you can't see the transform, then you're not using a webkit based browser. [Please see here for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: hi @Ohgodwhy I am using Google chrome and firefox I was not able to see the diagonal image

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to rotate the 'body' in the fiddle. 
As far as I know, that's not possible.

Try putting the background to a div tag covering the entire body, and rotate it. 

Plus, don't forget to add -ms-transform and transform for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: hi @T90 I have tried that also but the problem was the Image was not rendering can you guide me for that I want use for RWD (Responsive web design) and I want to make it as full stretch so I have used background-cover in my css

Comment: image not rendering? I tried it, but worked.<br/> for full stretch, give a size larger than 100%

Comment: hi @t90 thanks for your help but I want this diagonal should be in body full stretch that is what I have used background :url image path center fixed and background-size :cover so it will be full stretch